# What can I do to correct this Invalid syntax in line 11?

Tags: python

[python code with invalid syntax in line 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzfnq.png)

```
class bmi():
    def __init__(selfname,height_m,weight_kg):
        self.name = Name
        self.height_m = height
        self.weight_kg = weight

    def from_input(cls):
        return cls(
            input('Enter your name: '),
            print("Hello ", name)
            int(input('User ID: ')),
            int(input('Reputation: ')),
        )

        bmi = weight_kg / (height_m ** 2)
        print(bmi)
        if bmi < 25:
            print( name, "is not overweight")
        else:
            print( name, "is overweight")
```

Comment: There's a comma missing. But this doesn't seem to make much sense anyway. `print(...)` results in the value `None` being passed as second argument to `cls`. And all the code after `return cls(...)` won't be executed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python` 
class bmi():
def **init**(selfname,height_m,weight_kg):
self.name = Name
self.height_m = height
self.weight_kg = weight

```
def from_input(cls):
    return cls(
        input('Enter your name: '),
        print("Hello ", name),
        int(input('User ID: ')),
        int(input('Reputation: ')),
    )

    bmi = weight_kg / (height_m ** 2)
    print(bmi)
    if bmi < 25:
        print( name, "is not overweight")
    else:
        print( name, "is overweight")
```

Comment: @YersonDopazo you missed comma in return statement for that it is showing error you can use above code which i have corrected should work fine.